If I'm searching pictures to illustrate some crypto primitives? Can I ask it on th SE?
For example, a good picture to illustrate ZK proofs. Should I ask on the SE? Or in the Meta-SE?

First start from here https://www.iacr.org/authors/tikz/

@kelalaka I agree, that's a great resource. But I think that we still want to have these questions; finding a good illustration there might be tricky, or it may not exist there (I'm not saying that you do not agree with me about this :) ).

@MaartenBodewes When I say start from here, maybe we should write a canonical question so that if it is threre we dupe it.

No, just the fact that a resource is in a specific location doesn't mean that the question is a dupe. There may be problems with the resource after all, or there may be a choice between specific illustrations. Just pointing to the site is not an answer either.

In fact, I was thinking more a way to illustrate the concept (i.e properties), than the algorithms itself. It's more a pedagogical question, than a resource request.

No, this is on topic on the main site, cryptography. If asking for descriptions of cryptographic primitives is OK, then I don't see how asking for graphic representations isn't.
That said, just asking for tools or other resources isn't. We're not a human Google. Basically you would have to ask how you could draw a specific algorithm and make some effort to do it yourself before that. Only ask about where you get stuck drawing the primitive.
If there are already pictures about ZK proofs around, then please explain what is missing from them.

In other words, you can ask for graphical representations and such, but you would still need to take some time for your question to be on topic.

Meta is definitely not the place to ask, as it is about how the site operates. And you can always ask in chat, but you might just get chatter or nonsense back from the other participants.

If we allow in the main site, what will be the tag?

Um, good one. [tag:illustration] possibly? And of course the rest of the keywords, [tag:zero-knowledge-proofs] and such.

This kind of questions will have one line answer- if we don't draw here- that will decrease our site quality? This is another issue.

If somebody draws something then that would be preferable. Link only answers are actually not allowed, so you'd better be sure that the license of the source material matches our site, because you'd need to copy the source material. Just describing the illustration and then linking seems like a tricky thing to do.

In fact, when I write illustrate, I was more thinking to a mem than a tikZ picture. It's more a pedagogical question than a resource request.

Ah, OK, all the more reason for it to be on topic. But do explain your own thoughts and what you already know :)

In the main SE, Maeher is considering that it's off topic. I'm a little bit lost...

I think someone deleted the post (Maybe Maeher). I suppose it closes the debate. Could I have more details about how the final decision has been made (because on this discussion, it was unclear to me)?

Asking for clipart is not good for our site. We are not designers or looking for pretty pictures. I'm okay with some Tikz questions, though, not sure about the reputation badges;

You have gold in illustrations.
You have silver in illustrations.
You have bronze in illustrations.

doesn't sound Cryptography, right?
In my opinion, in general, this is a chat issue and most of the time the OP's will have a reputation to talk there.
So, I say NO
